# how to inject mock testing hapi with Server.inject

Tags: node.js, node-mysql, sequelize.js, hapi.js

I want to test hapi routes with lab, I am using mysql database.

The problem using Server.inject to test the route is that i can't mock the database because I am not calling the file that contains the handler function, so how do I inject mock database in handler?

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having? `inject` should work. `inject` should be identical to a real request from a coding standpoint.

Comment: I want to fake database calls while testing endpoints.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? looking to use hapijs for an API and  will want to mock db calls for tests.

Comment: @Adamski see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28820753/2372767) below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use something like [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to mock anything you `require`. For example, let's say you have a dbHandler.js somewhere:

```
var db = require('db');

module.exports.handleOne = function(request, reply) {
    reply(db.findOne());
}
```

And then in your server.js:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi'),
    dbHandler = require('dbHandler')

var server = new Hapi.Server(); server.connection({ port: 3000 });

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: dbHandler.handleOne
});
```

You can still mock out that call, because all calls to `require` are cached. So, in your test.js:

```
var sinon = require('sinon'),
    server = require('server'),
    db = require('db');

sinon.stub(db, 'findOne').returns({ one: 'fakeOne' });
// now the real findOne won't be called until you call db.findOne.restore()
server.inject({ url: '/' }, function (res) {
    expect(res.one).to.equal('fakeOne');
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'cached "require"'?

Comment: @MananVaghasiya see http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_cache . Once resolved, `require` will cache the object, and subsequent calls to `require` for a module will return the cached instance of said module.